# Treating a directory like a file in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

We have a tool which is designed to allow vendors to deliver files to a company and update their database. These files (generally of predetermined types) use our web-based transport system, a new record is created in the db for each one, and the files are moved into a new structure when delivered.

We have a new request from a client to use this tool to be able to pass through entire directories without parsing every record. Imagine if the client made digital cars then this tool allows the delivery of the digital nuts and bolts and tracks each part, but they want to also deliver a directory with all of the assets which went into creating a digital bolt without adding each asset as a new record.

The issue is that the original code doesn't have a nice way to handle these passthrough folders, and would require a lot of rewriting to make it work. We'd obviously need to create a new function which happens around the time of the directory walk, which takes out each folder which matches this passthrough and then handles it separately. The problem is that all the tools which do the transport, db entry, and delivery all expect files, not folders.

My thinking: what if we could treat that entire folder as a file? That way the current file-level tools don't need to be modified, we'd just need to add the "conversion" step. After generating the manifest, what if we used a library to turn it into a "file", send that, and then turn it back into a "folder" after ingest. The most obvious way to do that is ZIP files - and the current delivery tool does handle ZIPs - but that is slow and some of these deliveries are very large, which means when transporting if something goes wrong the *entire* ZIP would fail.

Is there a method which we can use which doesn't necessarily compress the files but just somehow otherwise can treat a directory and all its contents like a file, so the rest of the code doesn't need to be rewritten? Or something else I'm missing entirely?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [tar files](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html). Python has great support for it, and it is customary in *nix environments to use them as backup files. For compression you could use Gzip (also supported by the standard library and great for streaming).

Comment: The tar actually duplicates the data, right? So if there's 1TB of files to send, it creates a new file of 1TB, right? Or can it somehow wrap them "in place"?

Comment: Yes, it keeps the original files, but there are workarounds, my main concern is that tar is an archiver so it does not compress the data ,if you have a 1TB of data it might not be the right solution for you (I'm not even sure you can create a tar archive that big)

Comment: Yeah some of these will get pretty big (hopefully not a TB, but I should be prepared)